# Listen for application terminate from a library/framework?

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode

Is it possible to listen for the iOS application terminate/going to background mode from a library/framework, which is included into that app?

As I see, `dealloc` method (for a class which implemented in the library) does not called in case if whole app terminating (correct me if I'm wrong).

UPD.: The question is about libraries/frameworks. I know about `applicationWillTerminate` method for AppDelegate, but it's for the app itself, not for a library/framework.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Registering for `UIApplicationWillTerminateNotification` via `NotificationCenter` will work.

Code:

```
-(void)addAppTerminationNotifier
{
    [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self selector:@selector(appWillTerminate) name:UIApplicationWillTerminateNotification object:nil];
}

-(void)appWillTerminate
{
    //..... task to done before termination
}
```

Comment: Thank you! In general, it's working fine, just one thing – it's not working in case when app stopped from the XCode. Is there any event for this?

Comment: No, if the app is killed from Xcode or by the user swiping up in the app switcher then this notification will not be posted.

Comment: `appWillTerminate` only works when system terminates the app, it will not work when you forcefully kill the app

Comment: @Paulw11 BTW, it WILL send the event when user kill the app with swiping up (just checked, at least in Simulator).

Comment: Yes, you are right, but it won't when you stop debugging from Xcode.